# Hunting for PHP5 incompatibilities

Tags: php, php4

Something in here is incompatible with PHP5, but I am totally lost as to what. I have an .htaccess file on my web server that has the line "AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php", as it is required by just about everything else on the server and it defaults to PHP4...however; I need this one script to work, but it *only* works on PHP4. Any idea where the problem is?

```
<?  
/* config for the script */  
$download_path = "content"; /* path to your files, NB: no slash at the end */  
$sort = "asort"; /* array sorting - alphabetical sorting for the array */  

/* start the script... no more editing from here on... */  

/* get a list of the files + dirs and turn the list into an array */  
function file_list($dir) {  
  global $sort;  
  global $file_file_count;  
  if (is_dir($dir)) {  
    $fd = @opendir($dir);  
    while (($part = @readdir($fd)) == true) {  
      clearstatcache();  
      if ($part != "." && $part != "..") {  
        $file_array[] = $part;  
      }  
    }  
  if ($fd == true) {  
    closedir($fd);  
  }  
  if (is_array($file_array)) {  
    $sort($file_array);  
    $file_file_count = count($file_array);  
    return $file_array;  
  } else {  
    return false;  
  }  
  } else {  
    return false;  
  }  
}  

/* function to convert to Mb, Kb and bytes */  
function file_size($size) {  
  $megabyte = 1024 * 1024;  
    if ($size > $megabyte) { /* literal.float */  
      $re_sized = sprintf("%01.2f", $size / $megabyte) . " Mb";  
    } elseif ($size > 1024) {  
      $re_sized = sprintf("%01.2f", $size / 1024) . " Kb";  
    } else {  
      $re_sized = $size . " bytes";  
    }  
  return $re_sized;  
}  

/* get a list of the files/dirs, put them into a table. */  
function generate_file_list($path) {  
  global $download_path;  
  global $PHP_SELF;  
  $final_path = str_replace("//","/",str_replace("..","",urldecode($path)));  
  $file_array = file_list("$download_path/$final_path/");  
  echo "<b>$final_path/</b>\n";  
  echo "<br><br>\n\n";  
  if ($file_array == false) { /* check if the dir is an array before we process it to foreach(); */  
    echo "directory empty\n";  
  } else {  
    echo "<table width=\"75%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">\n";  
    echo "<tr><td><b>file</b></td><td><b>size</b></td></tr>\n";  
    foreach ($file_array as $file_name) {  
      $is_file = "$download_path/$final_path/$file_name";  
      $final_dir_name = urlencode($final_path); /* urlencode(); to prevent any broken links - decode on do_download(); */  
      $final_file_name = urlencode($file_name);  
      $file_size = filesize("$download_path/$final_path/$file_name");  
      $final_file_size = file_size($file_size);  
      if (is_file($is_file)) {  
        print "<tr><td><a href=\"$PHP_SELF?go=download&path=$final_dir_name&file=$final_file_name\">$file_name</a></td><td>$final_file_size</td></tr>\n";  
      } elseif (is_dir($is_file)) {  
        print "<tr><td><a href=\"$PHP_SELF?go=list&path=$final_dir_name/$final_file_name\">$file_name/</a></td><td>&lt;dir&gt;</td></tr>\n"; /* we don't need a size for a directory */  
      }  
    }  
    echo "</table>\n";  
  }  
}  
/* allow the user to download the file... */  
function do_download($path,$file) {  
  global $download_path;  
  $get_path = str_replace("//","/",str_replace("..","",stripslashes(urldecode($path)))); /* fopen adds \ to ' - so we strip 'em. */  
  $get_file = str_replace("//","/",str_replace("..","",stripslashes(urldecode($file))));  
    header("Content-Disposition: atachment; filename=$get_file");  
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");  
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize("$download_path/$get_path/$get_file"));  
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  
    header("Pragma: no-cache");  
    header("Expires: 0");  
  $fp = fopen("$download_path/$get_path/$get_file","r");  
  print fread($fp,filesize("$download_path/$get_path/$get_file"));  
  fclose($fp);  
  exit;  
}  

if (!isset($go)) {  
  $go = "dirlist";  
} if ($go == "dirlist") {  
    generate_file_list(""); /* null, so we get a list for the root directory */  
  } elseif ($go == "list" && isset($path)) {  
    if (isset($path)) { /* if the path is null - it returns a list for the root directory */  
      generate_file_list($path); /* get a list for the path specified */  
    } else {  
      generate_file_list("");  
    }  
  } elseif ($go == "download") {  
      if (isset($path) && isset($file)) {  
        do_download($path,$file); /* download the file... */  
      } else {  
    echo "no file selected to download :)\n";  
  }  
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is assuming that the ***$go***, ***$file***, and ***$path*** variables are being magically set. To get around this (and fix the script) you could change the beginning of the script to look like this:

```
<?  
/* config for the script */  
$download_path = 'content'; /*path to your files, NB: no slash at the end*/  
$sort = 'asort'; /* array sorting - alphabetical sorting for the array */  

/* start the script... no more editing from here on... */  
$go   = $_REQUEST['go'];
$file = $_REQUEST['file'];
$path = $_REQUEST['path'];

// ...
```

This use to work for you because of something known as [Register Globals](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). This is now turned off since it was a pretty big security problem and it led to sloppy coding practices.

Comment: Almost, there are isset calls in there. You want to do an if (isset($_REQUEST['go'])) {$go = $_REQUEST['go'];} to make sure the later code still works.

Comment: That isn't necessary. If there's no values for them then they'll be set to null. Null evaluates to false in isset().

Comment: Awesome, that worked great. This is actually some old code I picked up somewhere eons ago and just dumped it onto a local server for testing purposes--security is unimportant as the server is only open to the local network.

Answer (score 2):

When you've fixed the Register Globals issue suggested by fiXedd and jmucchiello, make sure you remove the reference to $PHP_SELF in the *generate_file_list* function. First, it doesn't exist like that anymore: it's now $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] but more importantly, the way your script is using it is exposing you to a cross-site-scripting issue.

Read more on this on: http://www.seancoates.com/xss-woes

Comment: Good catch, I totally missed those. :)

Comment: Yeah, I fixed them in my continued incompatibility hunting after posting this thread, though it was somewhat unnecessary as this is a local server only...so unless I plan on hacking myself I think it'll be fine. :O

This code is pretty ancient, so I guess it's to be expected that it'd be pretty horrible. It works for what I need though and I really didn't want to take the time to rewrite it.